# How to convert an HTTP response as string to an array?

Tags: java

I have an HTTP GET request to an API and I receive a JSON response as a string. However, this JSON is given as part of an array:

```
[
  {
     "test": "something",
     "another": "else"
  },
]
```

This response is what is provided but in a string format. Is there a way to find the first element of the array and then parse the JSON?

Code:

```
OkHttpClient http = j.getHttpClient();
                        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                                .addHeader("key", "<key>")
                                .build();
                        Response response = http.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: look at gson library

Comment: The snippet that you are showing there IS json. And parsing json in java is basically a solved problem. You pick a library like gson or jackson, you research how to use that library ...